# Partioning free space for manual install

Tags: linux-mint, partition, system-installation

I have 53 gigabytes that need formating into /root, /swap, /usr/, /var, /home, and /tmp. What is the best space allocation?

Comment: What will you use it for? For example, a server (small /home, big /srv) would be much different from a desktop (big /home).

Comment: for small machines RAM < 2GB swap=size(RAM) else swap=2GB and for larger machine RAM < 8GB swap=size(RAM) else swap=8GB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For my 40GB SSD drive, I partition the swap partition to be the same as my memory (i.e., I have 2GB of RAM, so is the swap partition.) I reserve about 10GB for /root, and the rest goes to /home. For your case, I think:

- Swap partition as said
- 14GB for /
- The rest for /home

I personally think partitioning for /usr, /var, and /tmp is too much trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is for desktop use, I would do something like this:

- /boot- 300MB
- /- 20gb (readonly if I want a faster boot, but it's usually annoying)
- swap- 2gb
- /home- rest of the drive

I like to keep a separate `/boot`, but you don't have to.

For a server setup, I would do something like this:

- /- 20gb (mounted read only)
- /root- 5gb
- swap- 2gb
- /srv- 5gb (read only, extended partition)
- /home- the rest (extended partition)
- /var- 5gb (extended partition)

I store all of my server stuff (web pages, etc) in `/srv` and leave `/home` for the bigger stuff. I keep `/srv` separate so I can reinstall / without losing my webserver data.

I would also mount /tmp as a tmpfs.

It really depends on the use case for the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a more modern filesystem like [btrfs](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) which, with its subvolume feature, eliminates the need to do this sort of planning at all.